# Sort by multiple columns in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, reverse, alphabetical

I have a file with 2 columns, "Name" and "Age", looking like this:

```
Alex,  15
Mary,  12
Alex,  28
Zoe,   16
Alex,  17
```

I will sort by the first column in alphabetical order, using `sort -t ',' -k1,1 filename.txt`, but if there are same names, I want the 2nd column to be sorted in the reversed way of how they were in the original file, like this:

```
Alex,  17
Alex,  28
Alex,  15
Mary,  12
Zoe,   17
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 21):

```
sort -t ',' -k1,1 -k2,2r filename.txt
```

or

```
sort -t ',' -k1,1 -k2r,2 filename.txt
```

The output is:

```
Alex,  28
Alex,  17
Alex,  15
Mary,  12
Zoe,   16
```

Explain: `-t` is to specify the field-separator, `-k` can be used to specify the start and stop position of field, and we could add a single letter `OPTS` for that field for ordering, for example `r` means to  reverse the result of comparisons.

Comment: This is not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 6):

Read file from back, sort by the first column and -s to preserve order in case of same value

```
tac filename.txt | sort -k1,1 -s
...
Alex,  17
Alex,  28
Alex,  15
Mary,  12
Zoe,   16
```

Answer (score 3):

Wops it seems I misunderstood your problem. I cannot find of a magic command, but a little script might do the job:

```
#! /bin/bash
declare names_sorted=$(cut -d, -f1 filename.txt | sort -k1,1 | uniq)
for name in $names_sorted ; do
    grep "$name," filename.txt | tac
done
```

Quick explanation:

1. first we assemble the sorted list of names: `$names_sorted`.
2. next (assuming the names do not contain white-spaces), we grep each name from the original list and revert that order with the command `tac`

Hope it's what you wanted this time ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
tac filename.txt | sort -t"," -k1,1 -s
```

Explanation:

- `tac` will sort the output in reverse order.
- `-t","` defines the field delimiter.
- `-k1,1` limits the sorting column to the first one only.
- `-s` preserves the order within the sorted rows.

Answer (score 2):

This should gives what you want:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2 filename.txt
```

Comment: no, -k2,2 is sorting again alphabetically, I want to sort the age column in the reverse way they appear in the file, first time.