# Can text be sorted twice?

Tags: bash, awk

I have an awk array that aggregates bytes up and downloaded. I can sort the output by either bytes down or up and pipe that to head for the top talkers; is it possible to output two sorts using different keys?

```
 zgrep ^1 20211014T00*.gz|awk '{print$3,$11,$6,$(NF-7)}'| awk 'NR>1{bytesDown[$1 " " $2]+=$3;bytesUp[$1 " " $2]+=$4} END {for(i in bytesDown) print bytesDown[i], bytesUp[i], i}'|sort -rn|head
```

Rather than parsing the source again to get the top uploads, I would like to be able to output the array again to "sort -rnk2|head".

I can see how I'd do it with a scratch file but is it possible/desirable to do it in memory? It's a bash shell on a 2 CPU Linux VM with 4GB of memory.

Comment: Since you're not using `awk` to sort; but just piping the output of `awk` into `sort`, you'd be looking at the terminal's `sort` command. You don't mention which OS/terminal you're using. If you're using linux/bash, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41231186/sort-by-multiple-columns-in-bash) might be a starting point. Looks like the [posix sort](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/sort/) is similar to bash, so that answer might work on MacOS and other posix systems as well

Comment: It takes far less memory to just find the largest and smallest items without sorting the rest than it does to do a full sort (and throw everything else away). Think about it: Finding the maximum and minimum in a list is never worse than O(n) CPU and constant memory usage (assuming the size of an individual item is bounded), whereas sorting the list is more like O(n log n) with worst-case performance that goes downhill from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear and there's no sample input/output to test with but this MAY be what you're trying to do:

```
zgrep '^1' 20211014T00*.gz|
awk '
    NR > 1 {
        key = $3 " " $11
        bytesdown[key] += $6
        bytesup[key] += $(NF-7)
    }
    END {
        cmd = "sort -rn | head"
        for ( key in bytesDown ) {
            print bytesDown[key], bytesUp[key], key | cmd
        }
        close(cmd)

        cmd = "sort -rnk2 | head"
        for ( key in bytesDown ) {
            print bytesDown[key], bytesUp[key], key | cmd
        }
        close(cmd)
    }
'
```

which could be written more concisely and efficiently as:

```
zgrep '^1' 20211014T00*.gz|
awk '
    NR > 1 {
        key = $3 " " $11
        bytesdown[key] += $6
        bytesup[key] += $(NF-7)
        if ( NR == 2 ) {
            max_bytesdown_key = key
            max_bytesup_key = key
        }
        else {
            if ( bytesdown[key] > bytesdown[max_bytesdown_key] ) {
                max_bytesdown_key = key
            }
            if ( bytesup[key] > bytesup[max_bytesup_key] ) {
                max_bytesup_key = key
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        print bytesdown[max_bytesdown_key], bytesup[max_bytesdown_key], max_bytesdown_key
        print bytesdown[max_bytesup_key], bytesup[max_bytesup_key], max_bytesup_key
    }
'
```

Comment: I have ~700 logs containing 200M+ records a day in flat files. Sometimes I need to parse them to get an aggregated view of a particular combination of the fields, sometimes I only need the top-n. I've been using awk arrays for both. Tripleee's tee gives me two views/outputs from the one parse. As you and Charles point out, that is very inefficient for a top-N view. Context can be key, so ideally I would want something like the top 10 of 1-n fields (up and down in this case). Would awk arrays come back in to play there?

Comment: I am still using awk arrays in both scripts I posted so it's not that awk arrays would come back into play, they would continue to be in play. Both scripts I posted give you 2 views/outputs from one parse, the main difference between my script and triplees is that I'm not using a bash-ism and a temp file, I'm doing it all portably in memory (except whatever `sort` chooses to do internally). If you want more than the top 1 values from each view then use the first script in my answer instead of the 2nd and just change `head` to `head -10` or whatever number of lines you want to see.

Comment: With GNU Awk you could [sort the array natively in Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html) and pluck off and print however many min or max values you want directly it the `END` block.

Comment: Rather than read the entire set into an array, sort and discard, is it practical to maintain an array of the top 10 as the data is read in? Speed is less of an issue than memory consumption; I'm realising that since my NAS was moved from a 40 CPU server (with memory to match, though I don't recall what) where I was getting a free ride to a 2 CPU VM with 4GB that I can't parse the logs in quite the way I used to... even when I tidy up my awk statements.

Comment: There are lots of options depending on what it really is you want to do. Your question asked here was `I would like to be able to output the array again to "sort -rnk2|head"....I can see how I'd do it with a scratch file but is it possible/desirable to do it in memory?` and I showed you how to do that so you should accept this answer to the question you asked and then ask a new question if you have a followup.

Comment: @imac I just took a look and your new question has even less information than this one did. You're supposed to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output, and your code along with a clear statement of your requirements and what problem you're running into. Your new question has no input, no output, no code, and it's asking for suggestions for software to use, not help with software you've written, which is an explicit reason to close questions on this forum which exists to help people with their code, not to provide code or suggestions for tools.

Comment: It's fine to provide a link to a previous question when posting a followup but your new question still has to make sense stand-alone, people shouldn't NEED to go looking at other questions to figure out what your current question is about. Please read [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples of how to ask questions on this forum if that's not clear.

Comment: Where does it stipulate that questions have to be code specific? The "how to ask" link states "Not all questions benefit from including code...". It also states "Introduce the problem before you post any code. In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself." I accept I could have reproduced some of the detail from this post if that's what people expect, but otherwise, tick...

Comment: This isn't my site so I don't have or care to look for links to the site charter or anything. Post whatever questions you like as far as I'm concerned, I'm just trying to help you get answers based on my experience of using the site and in that experience questions without code almost invariably get closed for not having code with a comment about the site being for helping people with their code. You could flag one of your questions for moderator attention and ask them for C&V if you like. Or maybe ask a question about that on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @Imac it took 3 different people to vote to close it - close votes are separate from downvotes. I personally would have just downvoted it and asked you to provide a [mcve] but if you didn't do that within a day then I would also have voted to close it. I see you've now added code to it but you're still missing the required sample input and expected output so I doubt it'll get reopened. I wouldn't have answered THIS question without sample input/output but someone else had answered it first and I didn't like that answer but thought you wouldn't get any other ones without sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

Bash allows you to do that with [process substitutions.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) It's not clear what you expect it to do with the data; printing both results to standard output is unlikely to be useful, so I send each to a separate file for later inspection.

```
zgrep ^1 20211014T00*.gz | 
awk '{print$3,$11,$6,$(NF-7)}' |
awk 'NR>1{bytesDown[$1 " " $2]+=$3;bytesUp[$1 " " $2]+=$4}
  END {for(i in bytesDown) print bytesDown[i], bytesUp[i], i}' |
tee >(sort -rn | head >first) |
sort -rnk2 | head >second
```

The double Awks could easily be refactored to a single Awk script.
Something like this?

```
awk 'NR>1{bytesDown[$3 " " $11]+=$6;bytesUp[$3 " " $11]+=$(NF-7)}
    END { for(i in bytesDown) print bytesDown[i], bytesUp[i], i }'
```

Comment: What is the tee >( ) doing? I can follow what's in and after the brackets but I'm not familiar with/canot get my head around what the redirect and brackets achieve...

Comment: In rough terms, the process substitution `>(...)` runs a command with standard input from a file-like object in parallel with the main process. So `tee` sees something like `tee /dev/fd/95` and obligingly writes a copy of its standard output there. Like Ed notes in a comment, on _some_ platforms this will involve a temporary file behind the scenes, but on modern Linux etc I believe it's all done with sockets under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @tripleee. BTW, I tried refactoring the awk but I think that has a gotcha. The log lines contain ~25 fields, several of which are sizable and one - URL - that is quite volatile in length; chaining the awks reduces the data being handled by the summation array. When run without the pre-filtering I was getting memory related issues/failures for jobs that ran fine with the old format.