# Efficient top 10 sort of multiple columns

Tags: sorting, awk

Looking for an efficient way to get the top 3 (expandable) of multiple numeric fields from a large data set on a Linux server; this is follow on to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70117001/8823709 where the best suggestion to

> "I have an awk array that aggregates bytes up and downloaded. I can
> sort the output by either bytes down or up and pipe that to head for
> the top talkers; is it possible to output two sorts using different
> keys?"

was :

```
zgrep '^1' 20211014T00*.gz|
awk '
    NR > 1 {
         key = $1 " " $2
         bytesdown[key] += $3
         bytesup[key] += $4
     }
     END {
         cmd = "sort -rn | head -3"
         for ( key in bytesDown ) {
             print bytesDown[key], bytesUp[key], key | cmd
         }
         close(cmd)
 
         cmd = "sort -rnk2 | head -3"
         for ( key in bytesDown ) {
             print bytesDown[key], bytesUp[key], key | cmd
         }
         close(cmd)
     }
'
```

However, as the data set can range from 1000's to many millions of rows, rather than read the entire set into an array, sort and discard the vast majority, is it practical to maintain an array of the top 10s as the data is read in? Absolute speed is less of an issue than memory consumption, a relatively limited resource on the server.

For example, given the following sample input:

```
ip1     fqdn101 101     10
ip2     fqdn102 102     11
ip3     fqdn103 103     12
ip4     fqdn104 104     13
ip1     fqdn101 105     14
ip1     fqdn102 106     15
ip1     fqdn103 107     16
ip1     fqdn104 108     17
ip2     fqdn103 109     16
ip2     fqdn104 110     17
```

That should output

```
ip1 fqdn101 206 24
ip2 fqdn104 110 17
ip2 fqdn103 109 16
```

and

```
ip1 fqdn101 206 24
ip2 fqdn104 110 17
ip1 fqdn104 108 17
```

Open to options other than awk - though that would be my default starting point - as long as they are available on the corporate Linux server build I'm given...

Comment: Could the logs go to a database instead of to flat files?

Comment: They do, but due to politics, I don't have access to that database. My team store 5TB of compressed logs in parallel, which is fine for spot checking but means that larger scale work needs to be chunked and aggregated. Most data has a long tail that is often of little/no interest, hence the desire for an efficient top N mechanism.

Comment: Could you take the flat files and put them into your own database to avoid the politics that your manager should know are retarding your work?

Comment: TBH, I haven't asked for a database. A copy of the log files need to be maintained as-is so a DB would require a beefier server and another 5TB+ of disk. Not impossible, and not without a significant overhead, but noted as an option.

Comment: As your file is not sorted and you add to your counters on the fly I do not see how you could avoid keeping track of all `$1 $2` keys. Indeed, if, at one point, you discard an entry `ipN fqdnXXX` with count `CNT` but the last line of your giant file adds 100 to `CNT` and makes it again one of the top keys, you will miss it. Is there another characteristic of your data set that you forgot to mention and that would solve this issue?

Comment: @renaud I see what you're saying; unless a minimum value filter is applied you need the full set. The top talkers pretty much exclusively have most of their traffic to/from one/few destination in chunky transactions so a filter might be the way to go.

Comment: @imac Another option: if you can afford this, first sorting your file by first and second fields would make all this very easy. All entries with same key would be contiguous and maintaining the top list with awk would become trivial.

Comment: Any whole-set actions limit the scope that can be looked at; there over 1B records a day in these logs. I currently chunk stuff at a device level (60x) but there are larger groupings that would be of interest if I could do it without overwhelming servers that were really only sized as NAS mount points. There are two servers (pri/sec) so I can run stuff on the secondary box without impacting logging activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said "Absolute speed is less of an issue than memory consumption", here's how to do what you want quickly and using minimal memory:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' 0

sort -k1,1 -k2,2 "${@:--}" |
awk '
    { key = $1 " " $2 }
    key != prev {
        if ( NR>1 ) {
            print prev, tot3, tot4
        }
        tot3 = tot4 = 0
        prev = key
    }
    {
        tot3 += $3
        tot4 += $4
    }
    END {
        print key, tot3, tot4
    }
' > "$tmp"

sort -nrk3,3 "$tmp" | head -3
printf '\n'
sort -nrk4,4 "$tmp" | head -3
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
ip1 fqdn101 206 24
ip2 fqdn104 110 17
ip2 fqdn103 109 16

ip1 fqdn101 206 24
ip2 fqdn104 110 17
ip1 fqdn104 108 17
```

The only tool in the above that has to handle the whole of the input at once is `sort` and it's designed to use demand paging, etc. to handle huge files so it doesn't need to be able to store the whole of the input in memory to be able to work. The temp file used above will be much smaller than your original input file as it only stores the totals for each of the key pairs.

If you don't want to use a temp file then you could do this which will take a bit longer (maybe 1.5 times?) to run:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

do1tot() {
    local totPos="$1"
    shift

    sort -k1,1 -k2,2 "${@:--}" |
    awk '
        { key = $1 " " $2 }
        key != prev {
            if ( NR>1 ) {
                print prev, tot3, tot4
            }
            tot3 = tot4 = 0
            prev = key
        }
        {
            tot3 += $3
            tot4 += $4
        }
        END {
            print key, tot3, tot4
        }
    ' |
    sort -nrk"$totPos,$totPos" |
    head -3
}

do1tot 3 "${@:--}"
printf "\n"
do1tot 4 "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
ip1 fqdn101 206 24
ip2 fqdn104 110 17
ip2 fqdn103 109 16

ip1 fqdn101 206 24
ip2 fqdn104 110 17
ip1 fqdn104 108 17
```

Comment: Thanks; what is "${@:--}" and what does the shift in the non-tmp file version do?
Interesting that the default end of a key is the end of line.

Comment: `"$@"` is the list of args passed to a function/script. `"${@:--}"` uses the args if present but if not (`:-`) then it uses stdin (`-`) so `"${@:--}"` means use any args provided or stdin otherwise so the function/script can operate on files or input from a pipe. The `shift` is to get past the `3` or `4` position value passed as the first arg to the function, thereby leaving just the input files in `"$@"`. I don't know what you mean by `the default end of a key is the end of line`.

Comment: I'd always assumed that the sort key was the field specified, i.e. -k1 sorted on field 1, but see that it includes the rest of the line by default; hence the -k1,1 you've used to specify the end of the sort keys.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, `-k` takes start,end specifiers.